# Check if value already exists in specific indices of List<double[]>

Tags: c#, list

In the example code below, I need help crafting a line of code in `someFunc()` that would return a vector of booleans equal to `False, True, False`, since the value of `100.0` is already contained in the second position of the first item of the list.  For the real-world problem I'm working on, I will need to call `someFunc` repeatedly and the number of vectors (of doubles) added to perv_vals may reach into the thousands.

```
// set up a list of vectors of type double
public static List<double[]> prev_vals = new List<double[]>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double[] arb_vals = new double[3];
    bool[] already_exists = new bool[3];

    // first example vector to be added to list
    arb_vals[0] = 10.0;
    arb_vals[1] = 100.0;
    arb_vals[2] = 1000.0;
    prev_vals.Add(arb_vals.ToArray());

    // second example vector to be added to list
    arb_vals = new double[3];
    arb_vals[0] = 11.0;
    arb_vals[1] = 101.0;
    arb_vals[2] = 1001.0;
    prev_vals.Add(arb_vals.ToArray());

    // third example vector to be added to list...could be thousands more
    arb_vals = new double[3];
    arb_vals[0] = 12.0;
    arb_vals[1] = 100.0;  # This value already exists at this position!
    arb_vals[2] = 1002.0;

    // Check whether latest entries of arb_vals 
    // already exist in their respective indices?
    already_exists = someFunc(prev_vals, arb_vals);

    // add latest iteration
    prev_vals.Add(arb_vals.ToArray());
}
public static bool[] someFunc(List<double[]> prev_vals, double[] arb_vals)
{
    bool[] alreadyExists = new bool[arb_vals.Length];

    // Need a line of code that would check if values contained in arb_vals
    // already exist in prev_vals IN THEIR RESPECTIVE INDICES 
    return alreadyExists;
}
```

Comment: So far, all you've provided is a specification, not a _question_. Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service. Please fix your post so that it includes a [mcve] that shows what you've tried so far, and an explanation of what that code does, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know if any combination exists anywhere in the previous array you could write the function like this (notice it returns a **single** bool):

```
public static bool someFunc(List<double[]> prev_vals, double[] arb_vals)
{
    var count = prev_vals.Where(x => x[0] == arb_vals[0] ||
                                     x[1] == arb_vals[1] ||
                                     x[2] == arb_vals[2]).Count();

    return Convert.ToBoolean(count);
}
```

But in your code sample above, your function returns an `array` of `bools` to let you know which value in the array previously exists.

For that you could write the function like this.

I took the lberty of taking it one step further and changing the `return type` of your function to return a `Tuple`. Now the function also tells you which `index` within the array contains the same value.

```
public Tuple<int, bool, bool, bool> someFunc(List<double[]> prev_vals, double[] arb_vals)
{
    // First use select to generate an index for each element of the array
    var searchResult = prev_vals.Select((v, i) => new { Index = i, Value = v }) 
                // Then use where to compare values
                .Where(x => x.Value[0] == arb_vals[0] ||         
                            x.Value[1] == arb_vals[1] ||
                            x.Value[2] == arb_vals[2])
                // if matches, select a new structure with the index num, and boolean values 
                .Select(p =>               
                    new
                    {
                        Index = p.Index,
                        val1 = p.Value[0] == arb_vals[0],
                        val2 = p.Value[1] == arb_vals[1],
                        val3 = p.Value[2] == arb_vals[2]
                    })
                .FirstOrDefault();

    if (searchResult != null)
        return Tuple.Create(searchResult.Index, searchResult.val1, searchResult.val2, searchResult.val3);

    return null;
}
```

**Update**

If the `arb_vals` array is of variable length that is only known at run time then you need to loop around it to compare.  This is going back to basics but this code somply loops through the `prev_vals` array searching for a match. If it finds one, it exits the function early.

```
public Tuple<int, int, double> someFunc(List<double[]> prev_vals, double[] arb_vals)
{
    for (int nLoopIdx = 0; nLoopIdx < prev_vals.Count; nLoopIdx++)
    {
        var item = prev_vals[nLoopIdx];
        for (int nBoolIdx = 0; nBoolIdx < arb_vals.Length; nBoolIdx++)
        {
            if (item[nBoolIdx] == arb_vals[nBoolIdx])
            {
                // This return the loop index, 
                // the bool index thats the same 
                // and the the bool value!
                return Tuple.Create(nLoopIdx, nBoolIdx, item[nBoolIdx]);
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I have also changed the return `Tuple` to: 2 ints and a double.

- The 1st int tells you the index of the clash in the prev_vals array.
- The 2nd int is the bool index that has the same value
- the double is the value that is the same

Comment: I think this unnecessarily restricts the size of the arrays so that the method can only be called if they are the exact, demo size which may or may not just be a limited example. Also, one should prefer ValueTuple these days over Tuple

Comment: Thanks @OceanAirdrop, the second bit of code you offered was definitely along the lines of what I was after.  As with the previous comment by pinkfloydx33, I'm wondering if there is a way to generalize so that the vector of doubles can be of a different length and not necessarily a vector with 3 positions?  Whatever the length is, it will always be consistent, but instead of 3 entries, each vector added to the list could have a length of 4 or 5 or more.  I didn't make that very clear in my original post.

Comment: Ahh I see.  Well, if the bool size is not fixed to 3 elements, then you could just keep it simple and use an old fashoned for loop.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much @OceanAirdrop.  A for loop makes sense.

Comment: Hi @pinkfloydx33 . Good point on ValueTuple.  I am behind the times on that one.

Answer (score 3):

You can try querying with a help of *Linq*, e.g.

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 bool exists = prev_vals
   .Any(array => array.Zip(arb_vals, (a, b) => a == b).Any());
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using Linq you can just cycle the array and the List

```
bool[] alreadyExists = new bool[arb_vals.Length];
        
for (int i=0; i < arb_vals.Length; i++) {
    foreach (double[] pv in prev_vals){
        if (pv[i] == arb_vals[i]){
            alreadyExists[i] = true;
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

As the array elements are initialized to False, you can just check first time an element is equal and continue to the next index.